ASP.net code web app (MVC) retrieving data from sql is bringing the old data to the first columns
I am retrieving alot of data from the datatabse which bring it into a paged list and datatable. I would like to reverse the order so my new transactions are displayed on the first page and not last page.Everything works good except i need to bring the latest to the first page
Controller Code
using Deadfiles.Data;
using Deadfiles.Models;
using Deadfiles.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


namespace Deadfiles.Controllers
{
    public class DeadfilesController : Controller
    {


        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public DeadfilesController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        // GET: Deadfiles
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,User,Viewer")]
        public Task<IActionResult> Index(int pg = 1)

        {
            List<Deadfile> deadfiles = [.. _context.Deadfiles];

            const int pageSize = 10;
            if (pg < 1)
                pg = 1;

            var recsCount = deadfiles.Count;
            var pager = new Pager(recsCount, pg, pageSize);

            int recSkip = (pg - 1) * pageSize;

            var data = deadfiles.Skip(recSkip).Take(pageSize).ToArray();
            this.ViewBag.Pager = pager;
            // return Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(View(data));
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(View(data));
            }
            else
            {
                return Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(this.Redirect("~/identity/account/login"));
            }


        }

Index Code
 @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@model IEnumerable<ApplicationUser>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Users";

}
<h1>Registered Users</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New User</a>
</p>


<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">User List</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-header -->
    <div class="card-body">

        <table id="rolesTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead> 
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                    <th>Email Address</th>
                    <th>User Role</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>    
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.FirstName)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.LastName)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Email)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Role.Name)</td>
                        <td><a asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Account" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-primary"><i class=" fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a asp-action="Delete" asp-controller="Account" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i>Delete</a></td>
                  
                    </tr>
            
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>                                                                  

Paging Model
namespace Deadfiles.Models
{
    public class Pager
    {
        public int TotalItems { get; private set; }
        public int CurrentPage { get; private set; }
        public int PageSize { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }
        public int StartPage { get; private set; }
        public int EndPage { get; private set; }

        public Pager()
        {

        }
        public Pager(int totalItems, int page, int pageSize = 30)
        {
            int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)totalItems / (decimal)pageSize);
            int currentPage = page;

            int startPage = currentPage - 5;
            int endPage = currentPage + 4;

            if (startPage <= 0)
            {
                endPage = endPage - (startPage - 1);
                startPage = 1;
            }

            if (endPage > totalPages)
            {
                endPage = totalPages;
                if (endPage > 10)
                {
                    startPage = endPage - 9;
                }
            }

            TotalItems = totalItems;
            CurrentPage = currentPage;
            PageSize = pageSize;
            TotalPages = totalPages;
            StartPage = startPage;
            EndPage = endPage;

        }


    }
}


I have spent days trying to get this to work

List deadfiles = [.. _context.Deadfiles]; while you loading order by apply like id desc it will load latest one on top
